# Como gerar um número randômico dentro de um intervalo?

Tags: ios, objective-c, random

Utilizando o médoto `arc4random_uniform()`, como devo montar a lógica para gerar um random dentro de um determinado intervalo?

Por exemplo, dado o intervalo [5, 10]

**Candidatos a random:**

> 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como a função permite determinar o máximo, só precisa fazer um deslocamento do mínimo.

```
arc4random_uniform(max - min) + min
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Swift/ObjC_RandomRange.m).

No seu exemplo:

```
arc4random_uniform(5) + 5
```